# Maximum Calculation Possible

Tags: ruby, for-loop, integer, max

I have a method to calculate the factorial of an input number

```
def fact( n )
  if (n == 0)
    1
  else
    n * fact(n-1)
  end
end
```

I want to create a loop that will test what the maximum possible calculable value is for this method. For my machine this number is 8734, but I found that through trial and error.

My idea is to create a for/ each loop and test whether the returned result is a real number or not. I only want to puts the last numerical value that actually produces a real numerical result.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as @spickermann suggests, but there is no need to search for the argument for `fact` at which the exception is raised.  Rather, just compute `fact(n)` for any suitably large value of `n` (e.g. `n = 100_000`), increment a stack depth counter each time `fact` is called, and report the value of that counter when the `SystemStackError` exception is raised. The following code performs that calculation for various values of `n`, showing that the value of `n` is not important, so long as it is suitably large.  I would think `n = 100_000` would be plenty large for any Ruby implementation, but make it a million if you like.

```
def fact( n )
  @stack_size += 1
  if (n == 0)
    1
  else
    n * fact(n-1)
  end
end

[10_000, 20_000, 50_000, 100_000, 8733, 8732].each do |n|
  print "n=#{n.to_s.ljust(6)}: "
  begin
    @stack_size = 0
    fact(n)
  rescue SystemStackError
    puts "stack level too deep at: #{@stack_size}"
  end
end

# n=10000 : stack level too deep at: 8733
# n=20000 : stack level too deep at: 8733
# n=50000 : stack level too deep at: 8733
# n=100000: stack level too deep at: 8733
# n=8733  : stack level too deep at: 8733
# n=8732  :
```

Note that the exception was not raised when `n => 8732`.

Does the maximum stack depth depend on the method? Most certainly! If we replace `fact` with:

```
def fact(n)
  @stack_size += 1
  fact(n-1)
end
```

we get:

```
# stack level too deep at: 9356
```

Comment: Hi Cary, Thank you very much this worked. I tried this approach on a few other methods I wrote and got the same answer. For example if I change the factorial to:

def fact( n )
  @stack_size += 1
  if (n == 0)
    1
  else
    2* n * fact(n-1)
  end
end

the 2 increases the value of the calculation much faster but the answer using this approach is still 8734. Does this mean my processor has trouble with the actual amount of arguments? Thank you very much.

Comment: I did an edit to show the maximum stack levels depends on the method, but I don't know what's going on under the hood.  For a complete understanding you'd probably have to dig through the C source, which, no doubt, varies by version.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
i = 1
loop do
  begin
    fact(i)
  rescue SystemStackError
    puts "stack level too deep at: #{i}"
    break
  end

  i += 1
end
```

Note that this is a very naive algorith that checks every number and might take some time. It would be must faster to Do some kind of binary search on a range of numbers.